# Display next elements with same class, breakpoint end of array

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, nativecss

I have a little specific problem.
This is my HTML structure:

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="level-1">Element 1 Level 1</li>
    <li class="level-2">Element 1 Level 2</li>
    <li class="level-2">Element 1 Level 2</li>
    <li class="level-2">Element 1 Level 2</li>
    <li class="level-1">Element 2 Level 1</li>
    <li class="level-1">Element 2 Level 1</li>
    <li class="level-1">Element 2 Level 1</li>
    <li class="level-2">Element 2 Level 2</li>
    <li class="level-2">Element 2 Level 2</li>
    <li class="level-2">Element 2 Level 2</li>
    <li class="level-2">Element 2 Level 2</li>
    <li class="level-2">Element 2 Level 2</li>
    <li class="level-1">Element 3 Level 1</li>
</ul>
```

Now, on Element 1 Level 1 hover, I need to display elements next to it with class level-2. Breakpoint is end of array of level-2 classes.

Expected result is showing every `li` with text Element 1 Level 2

Problem with:

```
li.level-1 + li.level-2 { display: block; }
```

Is that it will display only next element, not every element with `level-2` class.

This need to work like dropdown with nested levels, but with this kind of structure.

Problem is that I need to solve this only with CSS or CSS3.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to reach? Could you edit your question with the wanted result.

Comment: Please specify your problem and expected result in brief.

Comment: Question updated, I hope this is helpful.

Comment: @pavlovicnemanja : please check my answer now I have done some edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally one would put lower level items in separate ul's inside the li-item. The example you give is very bad practice since only humans can figure out it's actually a level lower in depth

BUT you should be able to do the following:

```css
.level-2 {
    display:none;
}

.level-1:hover ~ .level-2 {
    display: block;
}

.level-1:hover ~ .level-1 ~ .level-2 {
    display: none;
}
```

The `~` means **all items like x after this item** so `.level-1:hover ~ .level-2` means

> all .level-2 items after a hovered .level-1 item

The next statement `.level-1:hover ~ .level-1 ~ .level-2` is there to hide items with `.level-2` áfter another `.level-1` item.

NOTE: This doesn't help you much though as you will never be able to reach the lower depth items, because they disappear when you hover them.

EDIT: Also, this only works in relatively new browsers.

A good tree markup would be:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>first level link</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>second level link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then the markup would be easier and work cross-browser:

```css
ul ul li {display:none;}
li:hover ul {display:block;}
```

Comment: Great, this works for me! I know that my structure is bad, but I need to adjust to backend structure :( Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks. But as I pointed out above, try to avoid this kind of html/css in production environments as it will not work on all platforms and is really bad for the markup.

Comment: Also, Google WILL punish you for poorly formatted html. They have rakes and stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ~ selector in CSS just like in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/7nhy0yvn/

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    display:none;
}

ul li:first-child {
    display:block;
}

ul li:hover ~ li.level-2 {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: This only show the next item. He has multiple next level items after the first one.

Comment: OP has edite his question and as per that now I have edited my answer too.

Comment: The updated code shows all .level-2 items, even when they are not immediately after the .level-1 item that is being hovered. The items at the end of the list will display too though they have nothing to do with the first items.